# Rails calendar displays duplicate information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I have a calendar which I would like to display details of "visits" which belong to "users" and "branches". This works, in that each visit is displayed on the correct day with the correct information and only displays to the correct user. But for some reason each calendar entry is also showing an array of everything for its database entry like so:

```
[#<Visit id: 2, location: nil, date_from: "2015-08-12", time_from: "2000-01-01 10:30:00", date_to: "2015-08-20", time_to: "2000-01-01 09:15:00", comment: "trfghytrfg", branch_id: 2, user_id: 2>]
```

Obviously this doesn't look nice and I don't want it to appear, but I can't see where in my code that its coming from. If anyone can see where I'm going wrong that would be great.

visits_controller.rb:

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [ :new]
  before_action :set_visit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @visits = Visit.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @visits_by_date = @visits.group_by(&:date_from)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
    @users = User.all

  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @visit = Visit.new
    @branch = Branch.all
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @visit = current_user.visits.new(visit_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @visit.save
        format.html { redirect_to @visit, notice: 'Visit was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @visit }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @visit.update(visit_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @visit, notice: 'Visit was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @visit }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @visit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @visit.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to visits_url, notice: 'Visit was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_visit
      @visit = Visit.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def visit_params
      params.require(:visit).permit(:location, :date_from, :time_from, :date_to, :time_to, :comment, :branch_id, :user_id)
    end
end
```

visit.rb:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :branch  
    belongs_to :user #:as => 'created_by' 
    validates_uniqueness_of :time_from, :scope => [:date_from, :location], :message=>"slot is already taken on selected date"

end
```

calendar_helper.rb:

```
module CalendarHelper
 def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
    Calendar.new(self, date, block).table
  end


class Calendar < Struct.new(:view, :date, :callback)
    HEADER = %w[Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday]
    START_DAY = :sunday

    delegate :content_tag, to: :view

    def table
      content_tag :table, class: "calendar table table-bordered table-striped" do
        header + week_rows
      end
    end

    def header
      content_tag :tr do
        HEADER.map { |day| content_tag :th, day }.join.html_safe
      end
    end

    def week_rows
      weeks.map do |week|
        content_tag :tr do
          week.map { |day| day_cell(day) }.join.html_safe
        end
      end.join.html_safe
    end

    def day_cell(day)
      content_tag :td, view.capture(day, &callback), class: day_classes(day)
    end

    def day_classes(day)
      classes = []
      classes << "today" if day == Date.today
      classes << "not-month" if day.month != date.month
      classes.empty? ? nil : classes.join(" ")
    end

    def weeks
      first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
      last = date.end_of_month.end_of_week(START_DAY)
      (first..last).to_a.in_groups_of(7)
    end
end
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="visits">
<h2 id="month">

    <%= link_to "<-", date: @date.prev_month %> 
    <%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to "->", date: @date.next_month %>
</h2>
    <%= calendar @date do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %>
    <% if @visits_by_date[date] %>
    <ul>
        <%= @visits_by_date[date].each do |visit| %>
        <%= visit.branch.branch_name %>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= @visits_by_date[date].each do |visit| %>
```

Should be:

```
<% @visits_by_date[date].each do |visit| %>
```